# Log file php regex issue

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys I need some assistance with a php regex problem. Regex might not even be the best method to use here. I do not know how to use php at all - I just surf around looking at examples and try to paste them together to accomplish what I need done.

My current code looks like this...

```
// full path to text file
define("TEXT_FILE", "cports.log");
// number of lines to read from the end of file
define("LINES_COUNT", 5);


function read_file($file, $lines) {
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $linecounter = $lines;
    $pos = -2;
    $beginning = false;
    $text = array();
    while ($linecounter > 0) {
        $t = " ";
        while ($t != "\n") {
            if(fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) == -1) {
                $beginning = true; 
                break; 
            }
            $t = fgetc($handle);
            $pos --;
        }
        $linecounter --;
        if ($beginning) {
            rewind($handle);
        }
        $text[$lines-$linecounter-1] = fgets($handle);
        if ($beginning) break;
    }
    fclose ($handle);
    return array_reverse($text);
}

$fsize = round(filesize(TEXT_FILE)/1024/1024,2);

$lines = read_file(TEXT_FILE, LINES_COUNT);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}

?>
```

It basically reads a file named cports.log and tails the last 5 lines. However an example of my log file looks like this...

```
1/27/2013 7:16:06 PM Added          {92.255.176.84}
1/27/2013 7:16:07 PM Removed        {92.255.176.84}
1/27/2013 7:16:08 PM Added          {176.15.101.53}
1/27/2013 7:16:09 PM Removed        {176.15.101.53}
1/27/2013 7:16:23 PM Added          {98.119.183.235}
1/27/2013 7:16:24 PM Removed        {98.119.183.235}
1/27/2013 7:16:27 PM Added          {37.251.51.9}
1/27/2013 7:16:28 PM Removed        {37.251.51.9}
1/27/2013 7:16:38 PM Added          {92.255.176.84}
1/27/2013 7:16:38 PM Added          {82.112.38.83}
1/27/2013 7:16:39 PM Removed        {92.255.176.84}
1/27/2013 7:16:39 PM Removed        {82.112.38.83}
1/27/2013 7:16:45 PM Added          {74.61.121.147}
1/27/2013 7:16:50 PM Removed        {74.61.121.147}
```

So the output of my php file is just the last 5 lines of the log file. But what I need done is take each IP nested in the brackets and either store them into an array or a variable to be used in this section of code...

```
<?php

require_once("geoipcity.inc");

$ip = "8.8.8.8";

$gi = geoip_open("GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);

$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $ip);
    echo "Location One <br>";
    echo "Country: " .$record->country_name . "<br>";
    echo "City: " .$record->city . "<br>";
    echo "Latitude: " .$record->latitude . "<br>";
    echo "Longitude: " .$record->longitude . "<br>";

geoip_close($gi);
?>
```

This block of code is basically iterated 5 times to print out the geolocation of 5 IPs from whatever $ip is. Any help would be much appreciated! Once again I don't know php so please be patient with me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First tip would be using the [`file()`](http://php.net/file) function to read a file line-wise, then you can just iterate over them:

```
foreach (file("text.txt") as $line) {
    ###
}
```

But using a regex you could read the file at once and have [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) extract all IPs in one swoop:

```
preg_match_all('/\{([\d.]+)\}/', file_get_contents($fn), $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

With a nicely structured file like that, you can even completely arraytize all columns at once, using

```
#^  ([\d/]+)\s  ([\d:]+)\s \w+\s  (.*?)\s  \{([\d.]+)\}\s*  $#mix
```